# How to see IAM EventName CreateUser & DeleteUser in CloudTrail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudtrail

I'm new in AWS, we created an aws-controltower and test to create an IAM User in one of the AWS account, then the creation and deletion the IAM User is not logging in CloudTrail. I tried to create EC2 Instance with the said IAM User and it's showing in the CloudTrail.

We would like to see who created, modified and delete user in IAM with CloudTrail. Thanks!